# Emails not getting delivered to Hotmail addresses

Tags: email, spam

Recently Hotmail users are unable to receive their password email when they register or use the "Forgot my password" link to get a reset link emailed to them. So far this is only a problem for hotmail.

My emails are currently getting sent from my server (not an outside SMTP server). I just created an SPF record (but it may not have propagated yet). I do have one plugin that styles the emails called [WP Better Emails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-better-emails/).

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: You tagged this [tag:spam] - are the mails *not getting delivered* or do they end up in *junk*?

Comment: I have had trouble with HotMail before. The problem is with their over-zealous spam filters. This is not a WordPress issue.

Comment: @JohannesPille The emails are not getting delivered. They do not appear in the junk folder.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I think you're too quick to say that it's entirely unrelated to Wordpress. Yes, clearly Hotmail is ultimately filtering it, but their system isn't random and something about the form of the email dispatched by Wordpress (or something about my server) is triggering their filters. The question is what? Preliminary research indicates that something about the Wordpress emails are "malformed". Given this fact, and that this sort of thing is a known problem for many Wordpress site owners, I think it is appropriate to ask here.